# How should I wait for the document to load?

Tags: javascript

- Forgive me I am new to javascript.

I am trying to figure out the best approach to wait for a document to load.

What I am trying to do:

1. open a url
2. wait for the page to completely load (scripts, images, etc)
3. check if page loaded is true.

From my understanding I would do something like this:

```
window.location = "https://somewebsite.com"

function isLoaded() {
  while (document.readyState != "complete") {
  }
  return true;
}

isLoaded()
```

The problem:

- When I do this in Firefox's console. I get true - I believe - before the document has tried to open the page, or I get a "busy script" warning if I try to run it from the console after the current page is no longer on the screen.
- Maybe I am doing it wrong, maybe there is a better way to test, I am not sure.
- Little background. I am trying to write an Add On for Firefox, so my script will be run on the page and not part of the page. If that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Three options:

1. If script is the last tag of the body, the DOM would be ready before script tag executes
2. When the DOM is ready, "readyState" will change to "complete"
3. Put everything under 'DOMContentLoaded' event listener.

**onreadystatechange**

```
  document.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (document.readyState == "complete") {
     // document is ready. Do your stuff here
   }
 }
```

**DOMContentLoaded**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   console.log('document is ready. I can sleep now');
});
```

Comment: There seems to be some kind of disconnect in my mind. 

From the console if I load a page with window.location and then run document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   console.log('document is ready. I can sleep now');
}); I get undefined. Do I need to tell the browser delay or wait, or is there a better way to test this code?

Comment: Sorry for necroposting (this was the first result on a Google search), but to answer new searchers, that is because you're seeing the return value of the addEventListener function. It does its thing, which is create the event listener, and returns undefined—not the value of the anonymous function. The anonymous function will only be called when the event it's added to is actualized.